# Pagination inside Bootstrap tab [Laravel 5.1, Ajax, jQuery]

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.1

I want to insert several pagination function in one page using laravel pagination and bootstrap tab, but it doesn't work well, so I found something in Internet that say I need to use ajax to make it but I think there are some missing with my code because the component inside my tab is doesn't show. Here I provide my code:

View

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#f1").load("http://localhost/laravel/public/adminpanel/ajax/apu");
        $("#f2").load("http://localhost/laravel/public/adminpanel/ajax/aps");
        $("#f3").load("http://localhost/laravel/public/adminpanel/ajax/app");
    });
</script>

<div id="tf-header">
    <div class="container"> <!-- container -->
        <center><h1>Panel Administrator</h1></center>
    </div><!-- end container -->
</div>

<div id="tf-features">

        <div class="container"> <!-- container -->

                <div class="col-md-4"> <!-- tab menu col 4 -->

                    <ul class="features nav nav-pills nav-stacked" role="tablist">
                        <li role="presentation"> <!-- feature tab menu #1 -->
                            <a href="#f1" aria-controls="f1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                                <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x fa-fw"></i>
                                Anggota
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li role="presentation">  <!-- feature tab menu #2 -->
                            <a href="#f2" aria-controls="f2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                                <i class="fa fa-building fa-2x fa-fw"></i>
                                Sekolah
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li role="presentation">  <!-- feature tab menu #3 -->
                            <a href="#f3" aria-controls="f3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                                <i class="fa fa-briefcase fa-2x fa-fw"></i>
                                Proyek
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li role="presentation"> <!-- feature tab menu #4 -->
                            <a href="#f4" aria-controls="f4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                                <i class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-2x fa-fw"></i>
                                Verifikasi Pembayaran
                            </a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>

                </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8"> <!-- right content col 6 -->
                              <!-- Tab panes -->
                         <div class="tab-content features-content"> <!-- tab content wrapper -->
                                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="f1"> <!-- feature #1 content open ANGGOTA-->

                                </div>
                                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="f2"> <!-- feature #2 content open SEKOLAH-->

                                </div>
                                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="f3"> <!-- feature #3 content open PESAN TERKIRIM-->

                                </div>
                            </div> 
                </div><!-- end right content col 6 -->

            </div> <!-- end row -->
</div>
```

Controller

```
public function indexapu()
{
    $user = DB::table('users')->paginate();

    return View::make('adminpanelapu', ['users' => $user]);
}

public function indexaps()
{
    $school = DB::table('school')->paginate();

    return View::make('adminpanelaps', ['school' => $school]);
}

public function indexapp()
{
    $project = DB::table('project')->paginate();

    return View::make('adminpanelapp', ['project' => $project]);
}
```

Router

```
Route::get('/adminpanel/ajax/apu ', 'AdminControl@indexapu');
Route::get('/adminpanel/ajax/aps ', 'AdminControl@indexaps');
Route::get('/adminpanel/ajax/app ', 'AdminControl@indexapp');

Route::get('/adminpanel ', 'AdminControl@index');
```